# How to formulate a form with a variable in php

Tags: php, html, forms, variables

I'm trying to modify an existing html  which is output using echo.

```
<form action="/" id="searchForm" method="post">
```

I want to replace the "/" with $targetHost.

I can't seem to get the syntax correct.

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

```
<form action="<?= $targetHost ?>" id="searchForm" method="post">
```

`<?= $targetHost ?>` is a shorthand for `<?php echo $targetHost ?>`

Comment: I tried that using this snippet:
<?php
$targetHost="/mobile/index.php";
$matrix ='<form action="<?= $targetHost ?>" id="searchForm" method="post">';
echo $matrix .'<br/>';

The output looks like this:
<form action="<?= $targetHost ?>" id="searchForm" method="post"><br/>

Comment: if your html is wrapped in a string then you don't need to worry about the <?= ?>. Just use regular string concatenation.

`<?php
$targetHost="/mobile/index.php";
$matrix = '<form action=' . $targetHost . ' id="searchForm" method="POST"><p>Hello World</p></form><br/>';

echo $matrix;`
?>